# After plugging in a USB device, Win7 severely slows. What causes this and how could it be fixed?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, performance

This is the second PC undergoing this condition, both running Win7. On PC1 a Logitech device was connected through USB before installing it's branded driver (allowing windows to auto-install it), and PC2, a Wacom device was connected under similar conditions (windows auto-installed prior to installing the driver from the brand website). Since PC1 has been trashed, I'm mostly interested in reviving PC2.

**Note/Update: One common detail to mention is that the hardware was purchased new, however the devices were several years old at the time of connecting. I didn't spray or wipe dust (as there was no visible accumulation). Would there have been enough to cause an esd protection failure, yet not enough to disable any noticeable functionality? Could it be a bad cable? (It uses micro-usb and I may not have used the one that the device was shipped with.)

It's experiencing extreme slowness. Whereas I would formerly have been able to have multiple chrome windows open, now having anything more than two or three open is a joke.

There is very frequent HDD chirping which wasn't present beforehand. With barely anything open (just the few chrome windows), everything is painfully slow and overall, there is a higher occurrence of freezing and lagging, i.e. moving tabs, opening a new tab (takes up to 5 seconds vs. being almost instantaneous pre usb-hookup), activating a chrome window, loading a page, editing the address bar, maximizing, dragging or resizing a window, closing tabs, anything windows related such as navigating through the start menu or running explorer. However, in the absence of keyboard or mouse input, the HDD chirping eventually fades. Examining activity, it is pretty normal at rest (i.e. Idle Process is in the high 80's) and when not at rest the task at hand consumes an inordinate percentage of CPU.

When right clicking on the desktop, there is generally a wait of up to 30 seconds before the hourglass reverts to a cursor. Almost any mouse or keyboard action activates intense HDD chirping and Win lagging. PC2 is less than one year old, with 4GB of RAM and an Intel-G2030.

What caused this condition? and is there any way this can be fixed or avoided? It seems to have been inadvertently reproduced amongst these two PC's.

Is it worth starting a system restore, and would it actually change anything, especially in this sensitive condition (I've experienced anxious cases in which system restore lasted 1-2 hrs). I've read some posts about a 'bad' chip driver being responsible for this type of behavior. Is it possible that either of these devices somehow caused physical damage to the board by being plugged in? Would swapping out the HD or installing the OS in a new partition have any effect?

I feel that the best bet would be an attempt to reinstall windows on a new partition, but I'd like to garner tips on avoiding a recurrence of this issue as PC's and USB devices were built to work together and not to cripple each other. I.e., would having had inserted a wall-powered USB-multiplier as a buffer thwarted this problem all together?

<---------------------UPDATE---------------------------->

Thanks for the first response below. Using the suggested software, these are the summarized results after 1-2 minutes.

Under Main (the times vary, and are approximate), with increasing severity:

0:00: Message 1:

Your system appears to be suitable for handling real-time audio and other tasks without dropouts.

0:07: Message 2:

Your system seems to have difficulty handling real-time audio and other taks. You may experience drop out, clicks or pops due to buffer underruns. One problem may be related to pwer management, disable CPU throttling settings in Control Panel and BIOS  setup. Check for BIOS updates.

0:09: Message 3:

Your system appears to be having trouble handling real-time audio and other tasks. You are likely to experience buffer underruns appearing as drop outs, clicks or pops. One of more DPC routines that belong to a driver running in your system appear to be executing for too long. At least one detected problem appears to be network related. In case you are using a WLAN adapter, try disabling it to get better results. One problem may be related to pwer management, disable CPU throttling settings in Control Panel and BIOS setup. Check for BIOS updates.

```
interrupt to process current: I see it varying between 100 and 6000us
interrupt to process hi: 31993us
isr hi: 94us, ndis.sys
dpc hi, 9236us, ndis.sys
pagefault resolution hi: 448708us
```

Under Drivers:

```
[ordered by total]
ndis.sys exec: 9.2ms hi, 1600ms total 
usbport.sys exec:, .14ms hi, 400ms total
rspLLL64.sys exec: (highest DPC count), 
iastor.sys
tcpip.sys
```

Additionally, using the 'My Dell' tool (http://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/19/article/Product-Support/Self-support-Knowledgebase/software-and-downloads/support-center), it tells me that under Device Manager, there is one device without a driver (Ethernet controller) which is somewhat consistent with LatencyMon reporting NDIS lagging. I Installed ethernet and other drivers from (http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-660s/drivers) with the exception of high-risk updates such as bios and firmware and one or two updates had errors.

When disabling both the Wlan and lan, I still get Message3 right after opening any program (including chrome) and the high-use drivers listed are tcpip.sys, usbport.sys, nbit.sys and storeport.sys, and at one point Hal.dll also has a high isr count.

Still high-latency, performance has not appreciably changed.

Would it be worthwhile to disconnect the hardware (tried) and uninstall its driver?

Update: Used ShellEx to disable all non-Microsoft items, with unnoticeable performance improvement.

Comment: We need to identify exactly what driver/service is responsible. Please download and run **LatencyMon** (http://www.resplendence.com/latencymon), it's a brilliant profiler that should help identify the culprit. Run it for a minute or two while your system is misbehaving then check the various result tabs (Main, Stats, Processes, Drivers, CPUs). That might be enough for you to go on, if not, try post some of the results here and we'll try figure it out!

Comment: I should mention that LatencyMon is free and free of any kind of crap-ware so it's safe to use. I have no association with the software other than the fact I use it and it has served me well.

Comment: check your power plan in control panel, be sure it is set to "performance"

Comment: Moab - thanks, yes, done. Just to remind you, everything was fine before installing the hardware.

Comment: Since you are describing Windows Explorer problems, look to see if there ary any Shell Extensions associated with the new hardware: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Comment: you should definitely check eventvwr. So run it and go to administrative events. There may be some useful errors or warnings

Comment: Latencymon is not telling you anything useful. It is noticing, as you already have, that your computer is taking a long time to respond.

Comment: @user3645994 does this occur only with the wacom/logitech device? Or any USB devices?

Comment: All this seems a driver issue to me. Try updating to latest drivers, or roll back to previous stable drivers. Or maybe faulty mouse and keyboard? Have you tried to plug another (different) mouse and keyboard to your PC?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the driver. To update the driver you have two options:

1. Find a driver at the manufacturer's website.
2. Find the hardware ID and download from a driver repository site. In order to find the hardware ID do the following: Open Device Manager > Find the device your looking for in the list > Right-click the device > Click "Properties" > click the "Details" tab > In the Drop-down menu choose "Hardware Ids" and you will see a list of Hardware IDs.
   Copy one of the hardware ID's, then post into the search field at [www.devid.info](http://devid.info). There your likely to find the driver. Download the driver your looking for (preferably the one packaged by devID as they strip the drivers for unnecessary junk). Run the .exe and the driver will install itself. Make sure the device is connected when installing the driver.

Answer (score 0):

restart the pc  with the  usb `plugged in` then restart it with thee  usb  `unplugged` and  se the differance , if the usb slows the booting , it means tthe usb maybe  is damaged or needs reformat

Answer (score 0):

> Almost any mouse or keyboard action activates intense HDD chirping and Win lagging. PC2 is less than one year old, with 4GB of RAM and an Intel-G2030.

This sounds like something is writing to disk every time there is a mouse or keyboard event.  Keylogging or screen recording malware may do this.

Check your audio drivers and update them - there recently was a Conexant or similar driver that was mistakenly keylogging all keypresses.  HP (the manufacturer of the systems I was working on at the time) issued an updated driver.  If the system has a mechnical hard drive rather than SSD, the noises you hear may be related, and the system slowdown may be due to the driver waiting for writes to the slow DD

If not, check for malware.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with my usb ADSL modem on any computer I connect it to. This means, it's probably the driver that is making Windows misbehave.

Updating your driver, or, if that fails, downgrading to an older version may help the problems you're experiencing.

Comment: You having the same problem and sharing that fact, does not really answer the author's question.

Answer (score -1):

It's the Windows 7 driver issue.

**The problem is with Windows 7.** It isn't just you.

When you install a new device, Windows will search for any drivers it has to let you use it. Windows 7 has many drivers stored locally and depending on how fast disk access is, it might take a long time for it to identify which driver to use.

I had the same issue for a long time as I had not yet got in windows 8.1.
I recommend you to upgrade.

Also please note that clearing the driver folder or junk drivers probably wont help you out at all. I had tried it and it failed miserably for me. My suggestion is to try *upgrading* your OS.

Comment: This particular slowdown only applies the first time the computer sets up the driver.  It shouldn't do this again unless you plug the device into a different port, or unless it never successfully installed previously.

Comment: But it does happen with windows 7. I had the same issue and it got solved when I upgraded to windows 8.1.1 .

Comment: and yea., I had tried reinstalling my whole windows due to this. but again after some months I got into the same problem.